# Clock initialized by server then run by client is late

Tags: javascript, timing

I want to create clock that its time initialized by server and then continues with client with this codes:

```
//initializing by server(ASP.NET):
<% var now=System.DateTime.Now; %>
var h=<%=now.Hour %>;
var m=<%=now.Minute %>;
var s=<%=now.Second %>;

//then client:
function startTime() {
   s++;
   if (s == 60) {
       s = 0;
       m++;
       if (m == 60) {
           m = 0;
           h++;
           if (h == 24)
               h = 0;
       }
   }
   m = checkTime(m);
   s = checkTime(s);
   h = checkTime(h);
   document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
   t = setTimeout(function () { startTime() }, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {

   if (i < 10) {
       if(i.toString().length<2)
           i = "0" + i;
   }
return i;
}
window.load = startTime();
```

but clock become about 5 seconds late for each 10 minute.

How can I prevent this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is not a precise enough to do exact timing. It can easily be off by as much as `10ms` even when nothing else is going on. Over long periods of time this will skew your clock.

An alternative way to implement the clock is to use the native `Date` object to do the calculation for you, relying on the system clock, and only use `setTimeout` to visually update the time.

Now since `setTimeout` can't reliably update the time every second you can set to `100ms` so it will try to update 10 times per second. If your time calculation isn't too heavy this should work nicely.

Check the spec to learn how to use `Date`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date (Mozilla Firefox)

Comment: how to use `Date` with initial values?

Comment: if I use `Date` it will be client's time after all.

Comment: No you just use `Date` to do the seconds-timing since it can reliably tell you how many seconds have passed.

Comment: see my answer. is that your mean?

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
//initializing by server(ASP.NET):
<% var now=System.DateTime.Now; %>
var d=new Date();
var h=<%=now.Hour %>;
var m=<%=now.Minute %>;
var s=<%=now.Second %>;
var sec=d.getSeconds();

//then client:
function startTime() {

    var date = new Date();
    if (date.getSeconds() != sec) {
       sec = date.getSeconds();
       s++;
    }
   if (s == 60) {
       s = 0;
       m++;
       if (m == 60) {
           m = 0;
           h++;
           if (h == 24)
               h = 0;
       }
   }
   m = checkTime(m);
   s = checkTime(s);
   h = checkTime(h);
   document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
   t = setTimeout(function () { startTime() }, 100);
}

function checkTime(i) {

   if (i < 10) {
       if(i.toString().length<2)
           i = "0" + i;
   }
return i;
}
window.load = startTime();
```